# How can I send an e-mail whenever user registration fails?

Tags: users, forms

I am a bit concerned that my user registration is too complicated.  I have done some basic usability testing, but I'm still not confident, so what I'd like to do is send an e-mail to myself every time a user makes a mistake on the registration form that requires a correction before registration can be processed (Mollom validation fails, no input in a required field, etc.)

Is there an easy "catch-all" way to do this for all possible mistakes users can make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how *deep* you want to go, but here's what I would do.

- Create a custom module, "mysite_utils" (I always make at least one
  custom module to do some custom tweaks.)
- Create a [mysite_utils_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)
  function.
- In that form_alter function, look for the user registration form_id.
- Add a custom validation handler `mysite_utils_user_register_validate().`
- Put your validation checks in that function. If the validation fails,
  send yourself an email.

This process will require a lot of custom coding, not sure what your Drupal level is.

Comment: I do have a custom module and I can add the custom validation handler.  But is it possible to automatically trigger the handler somehow if Drupal's built-in checks fail?